# Is it best practice to place an editable data table in a modal/popup?

Tags: data-tables, drag-n-drop, modal

I am curious if this is already established as best practice but so far I haven't seen any standards on this.
Let me know your thoughts.

**Scenario is:**
We are trying to go with either V1 or V2 inside the modal.

V1: a data table structure in a modal to add users (it can be up to 100)

V2: drag and drop the users with 2 column boxes (box 1:assigned users) and (box 2: unassigned users)

Answer (score 1):

V2 sounds better and a more established pattern. It's better because the users' attention stays in the same place without it getting interrupted by a modal.

Modals have a time and a place, but this interaction sounds wrong to me.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if I understood correctly, do you want to connect V1 and V2?

**Tabs** are solution come to my mind
[image]